# If multiple objects access new object instance then synchronization is not required?

Tags: java, multithreading

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html states

> Counter is designed so that each invocation of increment will add 1 to
>   c, and each invocation of decrement will subtract 1 from c. However,
>   if a Counter object is referenced from multiple threads, interference
>   between threads may prevent this from happening as expected.

This is true if the multiple threads reference the same Counter object instance ? If multiple threads are each accessing the a new unique(to that thread) counter instance then synchronization is not required ?

Comment: Why the confusion? What makes you think synchronization would be required?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I geuss I was not aware if newly created instances of same objects are operated on in isolation from a threading point of view  - they are operated on in isolation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to quote from your [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interfere.html):

> [...] However, if a `Counter` object is referenced from multiple threads,
>   **interference** between threads may prevent this from happening as expected.
>
> **Interference happens when two operations, running in different threads, but acting on the same data, interleave.** This means that
>   the two operations consist of multiple steps, and the sequences of
>   steps overlap.

If each of your threads has its own `Counter` instance, then they are not acting on the *same data*. Therefore, there is no interference and synchronization is not required.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you are sure that they are unique instances, then you don't need to synchronize. You will only need to synchronize if multiple threads are accessing and modifying the the *same* instance (shared state).